# Infinite number of composite pairs $(6n + 1), (6n -1)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I came across a problem in Dudley's *Elementary Number Theory*. Part (a) is to find one $n$ such that both $6n+1$ and $6n-1$ are composite. So I stumbled across $n=50$, which gives $299=13 \cdot 23$, and $301=7 \cdot 43$

The motivation for this was knowing that $9|10^k -1$ and $7|10^{2k}+1$ and trying to find an even power of ten (obviously $300$ is not a power of ten).

Part (b) asks to prove that there are infinitely many $n$ such that both are composite.

**How do we show this?**

Setting $6n \pm 1 = 10^{2k} \pm 1$ didn't work.

I looked at $(6n+1)(6n-1) = 36n^2-1 = 6(6n^2) -1$, so I can generate composite numbers of the form $6m -1$, but what about the corresponding $6m+1$ ?

Should I be using my result from (a) to generate these pairs?

I looked at the solutions to [this related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/15075/7850), but they seemed focused on proving that both are *prime*.

Other methods that I've considered are using modular arithmetic (though that hasn't been covered at this point in the book) and using the well-ordering principle in some way...
(Hints are acceptable, as I want to be an autonomous mathematician, as much as possible)

---

**Added**

If we let $n = 6^{2k} = 36^k$, then $6n \pm 1 = 6^{2k+1} \pm 1$, which (for $k \geq 1$) factors into $(6 \pm 1)(6^{2k} \mp ... +1)$

Is this correct? Here I am using a factorization of sums/differences of odd powers, which "hasn't been covered" (which isn't itself a problem).

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem, $6x\equiv 1 \pmod{47}$, $6x\equiv -1 \pmod {61}$.

Comment: @André, I will try to digest this, thanks!

Comment: @Andre: That's really nice. I like that a lot.

Comment: You don't need to use $47$ and $61$, any pair of primes relatively prime to $6$ will do.  @AndréNicolas. For example $6x\equiv 1\pmod 5$ and $6x\equiv -1 \pmod 7$ yields $x\equiv 1\pmod {35}$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: I picked two numbers that were obviously not special, though unfortunately I picked two primes. Thought that perhaps the OP could chase this down to get a family of examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Instead of even powers of $10$, try odd powers of $6$.

Comment: Ah yes! I will show my work, many thanks.

Comment: @TheChaz: Your edit is correct :-) $x^{2n+1} + 1$ is divisible by $x+1$ and $x^{2n+1} - 1$ is divisible by $x-1$.

Comment: Great. $$$$ $$$$

Answer (score 3):

Try to make the expressions fit forms that you know factor. Sums and differences of cubes factor.  So $n=6^2k^3$ will make the expressions take on those forms.

Comment: That's the final step that I was missing. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way of solving the problem "non-constructively"

You can find infinitely many disjoint sequences of $8$ consecutive composite numbers, and among any 8 consecutive numbers you can find a pair of the type $6n \pm 1$.

Once you figure this "non-constructive" solution, the standard examples lead to simple solutions. For example, it is easy to figure that $k!+5, k!+7$ work for all $k \geq 7$... This would lead to $n= \frac{k!}{6}+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Replacing $n$ by $m-1$ (or you could also use $t+1$)

gives you          $$6n+1=6m-5$$
                   $$6n-1=6m-7$$
let $m=35r$, then you get $$6(35r)-5= 5 [6(7r)-1]$$
and                     $$6(35r)-7= 7 [6(5r)-1]$$