# How to prove that a number is composite?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

How can one prove that a number is a composite number? I'm trying to prove that $6n + 1$ and $6n - 1$ are both composite for an infinite amount of integers $n$, with $n$ greater than or equal to $1$. I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Show there are infinitely many $n$ so one's a multiple of 5, the other, of 7.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/102493/infinite-number-of-composite-pairs-6n-1-6n-1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example n=35*k+34.We obtain that one number is divisible by 5 and the other by 7.

Comment: Thank you! How did you come up with this?

Comment: You can to choose other numbers.Observ that  is sufficiently to find a particular solution in our case is 34.35 is exactly 5*7.

Answer (score 2):

$6(10n+6)-1=60n+35$ is composite (divisible by $5$) for every $n$.

$6(10n+6)+1=60n+37$ is composite (divisible by $37$) for every $n=37k$.

Hence $6(10n+6)-1$ and $6(10n+6)+1$ are composite for every $n=37k$.